# AWS secure REST API with mutual authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to secure a REST API with mutual authentication on AWS. This means, only clients with a specific client certificate should be able to access the API. What is the best way to secure a REST API on AWS with mutual authentication?

I know, there is [client certificate support for API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html), but this is not what I am looking for. As far as I understand, this only authenticates Api Gateway against backend and is not able to authenticate clients to Api gateway.

Is Api Gateway, Load balancer or any other AWS product able to do mutual authentication to secure a rest API or do I need to implement this by my own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to do this on your servers.

None of the services that terminate TLS and forward requests or connections to your app tier -- Elastic Load Balancers (Classic, Application, and Network), CloudFront, or API Gateway -- support TLS mutual auth.

Of course, a Network Load Balancer without TLS termination or a Classic Load Balancer in TCP mode will pass-through your payload, whatever it is, so either of these can be used in front of your servers, but the servers will need to handle all the TLS.

Also, your conclusion is correct that API Gateway's client certificates are not what you are looking for.  They work as you described them.

Comment: Thank you. I am hoping this feature will be available sometime on AWS. Can anyone refer a reference implementation how this can be done on AWS (e.g. using nginx)?

Answer (score 6):

As of 17th September, 2020, support for Mutual Authentication using TLS is available on AWS API Gateway: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-api-gateway-supports-mutual-tls-authentication/ . It can be used to authenticate clients calling an API on API Gateway.